# How to test software by modeling its states with Quantum Computing

Tags: redux, automation, automated-tests, quantum-computing

I've heard that Quantum Computing can model systems with large numbers of states.  For example, if I understood the article cited below, a Quantum Computer with 50 qubits can simultaneously model 2^50 possible states.  Moreover,

> Quantum computers, which can exploit purely quantum features such as
>   superpositions and entanglement, should be able to efficiently produce
>   a series of samples...For classical computers, however, there’s no
>   known fast algorithm for generating these samples.
>   [Quantum Supremacy Is Coming: Here’s What You Should Know](https://www.quantamagazine.org/quantum-supremacy-is-coming-heres-what-you-should-know-20190718/)

In testing software, we first have to generate samples.  Could a series of qubits instantly generate those samples...and test if the system under test handles them correctly?

Within software, Redux applications in particular are easy to test because you can initialize them with any state you want, but there are a lot of them.

Since Redux applications have large numbers of states, I am wondering, can Quantum Computers be used to test Redux applications by simultaneously representing the many states in the Redux store?

How do I model the Redux states with qubits?

How can the Quantum Computer simultaneously test all of those states?

How do I tell the Quantum Computer whether a test passed?

Comment: Quite good question! Do you actually have a Quantum Computer just for testing? Or you gonna use something like AWS Braket ?

Comment: That or [IBM Quantum Experience](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/login), but before that I'm stuck conceptually.